# ¿Como extraer los datos de un array y mostrarlos en una texbox?

Tags: c#

estaba probando en extraer datos de un txt y mostrarlos en una texbox a traves de un boton. Lo que quiero hacer es que se muestre el valor inicial de la posicion 1 asta el final del array, pero al momento de usar el array tengo el problema de que esta fuera de los limites.

**Nota** : el archivo que uso tiene un total de 164942 lineas

```cs
private void boton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string coord = "";
            List<string> linesX = File.ReadLines(@"C:\EyeMatris\Coordenadas\CoordenadasX.txt").ToList();
            string[] arrayX = linesX.ToArray();
            textBox1.Text = " "+arrayX.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i <= arrayX.Length; i++)
            {
                if (coord == arrayX[i])
                {
                    textX.Text = coord;//<--Aqui deberia mostrarme cada valor asta termininar de leer el array
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es necesario usar un arreglo ya que como tu dices solo lo motraras puedes usar algo como esto pero tu txt debe ser multiline

```
  textBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"RutaArchivo");
```

Imagen de que si funciona
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pero por ejemplo tengo este orden de datos en el txt _254, 214, 542, 125_ todos se mostraran de uno en uno en la texbox?

Comment: Lo probe pero la texbox no me arroja datos se queda en blanco, o pasan tan rapido que no se visualizan?

Comment: Claro aqui esta [enlace] (https://www.mediafire.com/file/acfgw2ftefy2p2l/CoordenadasX.txt/file)

Comment: Revise las propiedades de mi texbox no tendra que ver el readOnly true?

Comment: es tal como dijiste `textBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\EyeMatris\Coordenadas\CoordenadasY.txt");`

Comment: Creo que es por que mi texbox en relativamente pequeña, la hice pensando en que se mostrara un dato a la vez no todos en forma de lista

Comment: Si era eso, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Como son muchas líneas intenta con un StringBuilder

```
private void boton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                StringBuilder coord = new StringBuilder();
                List<string> linesX = File.ReadLines(@"C:\EyeMatris\Coordenadas\CoordenadasX.txt").ToList();
                string[] arrayX = linesX.ToArray();

                textBox1.Text = " "+arrayX.Length;

                for (int i = 0; i < arrayX.Length; i++)
                {
                    coord.AppendLine(arrayX[i]);
                }

                textX.Text = coord.ToString();
            }
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Lo probe pero me manda aun el error de indice fuera de los limites de la matriz

Comment: Prueba nuevamente, copia y pega

Comment: Realice la prueba otra vez pero la texbox no mostro nada, sera que los datos pasan muy rapido?

Comment: me sale un error de que no es posible converter un <char> a un <string> al cambiarlo por File.ReadAllText

Comment: tienes razón, es con la función File.ReadLines con eso ya debería mostrarte la información.

Comment: Creo que a de ser las propiedades de mi texbox, lo checare